# Opening Solution with Visual Studio 2008 is broken

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Some of the the Solution icons are broken and appears as follow. 
[image]
I can simply load this using Visual Studio and I manually confirmed the content of the solution file to make sure that there's nothing wrong. But still some of the icons appears as above and I can't open on double clicking.

I can simply open the proper solutions which displays the solution icon as follows. 
[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: The first icon appears as that of an [.suo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try recreating the solution from scratch.  It only takes about a minute.  Rename the existing solution and create a new empty solution and add the projects one by one.  Once the new solution is in place, use a diff tool to figure out why the old one is acting strangely.  My guess is that someone tried editing it manually and they hosed some of the formatting.

Comment: Did you try recreating the .sln file?  I'm positive that would resolve your issue.

Comment: Recreating the sln file is OK. End of the day, it's an XML file. So I am curious to know what it takes to make this difference.

Comment: FYI - they're not XML files.  They are plain text files which is why I'm telling you to recreate the sln file and get it to a working state.  At that point, you can use a diff tool like WinMerge to compare the working sln file with the broken one.